# setInterval Returning Value

Tags: javascript, dom, closures, setinterval

I am working with a setInveral function and I would like to access the value that have been calculated during the interval and return them later.

The function itself, look if an element is finished to load (through Ajax) for a number of time and then return the JSON parse of that element if it is finished (or return blank). 
It is possible that the element is finished loaded after 200ms or 1s. In order to be the quickest possible, I am actually using setInterval.

My function look like this :

```
window.ObjectBuilding = function (id){ /*function to check the element & 
return Object*/
/*Set max number of loop*/
var dl_cap = 5;
/*Set the intervals (in milliseconds) on how often to execute the code*/
var dl_int = 200;
/*Counter*/
var check_dl_inc = 0;
/*initiate global var*/
window.temp_object='';
check = setInterval(function(){
    el = window.document.getElementById(id);
    if(el){
        if(el.innerHTML.length > 50){
            /*Object ready*/
            temp_object= JSON.parse(el.innerHTML);
            clearInterval(check);
        }else{
            /*Oject not yet ready*/
            check_dl_inc++;
            if(check_dl_inc == dl_cap){
                temp_object= "";
                clearInterval(check );
                }
        }
    }else{
        /*Missing Dom element*/
        temp_object= "";
        clearInterval(check );
    }
}, dl_int);
return temp_object
}
```

The idea is to then use this object to a multiple place on my website such as : 
`object = ObjectBuilding('myID')`

The problem I encounter is that the `temp_object` is never updated with the latest value. It always remain as the initial state.

I think this is a closure thing but I didn't find a way to get around it. 
The SetInterval return value is the ID of the temporal object so I cannot get that.

Comment: If your `setInterval()` is clearing itself in all cases, then why not use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I didn't want to wait for 1s if the object can be built in 200ms, so I can go as fast as possible.

Comment: So? You can set it to any value you like. Who says it has to be 1s? Just set the `setTimeout()` to delay 200ms then.

Comment: But not sure if the element will be loaded in 200ms... :(
So I check every 200ms for 1s
Let's say 1s is the maximum that I can wait and if I can get faster, it is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning **temp_object**, but the timer starts and executes later. So the return value is still an empty string when you return it.

If you want to update your page then call a function instead of trying to return:

```
function updateMyPage(temp_object) { 
    // update your page here, now you have the updated value in temp_object
}

window.ObjectBuilding = function (id){ /*function to check the element & 
return Object*/
/*Set max number of loop*/
var dl_cap = 5;
/*Set the intervals (in milliseconds) on how often to execute the code*/
var dl_int = 200;
/*Counter*/
var check_dl_inc = 0;
/*initiate global var*/
check = setInterval(function(){
    el = window.document.getElementById(id);
    if(el){
        if(el.innerHTML.length > 50){
            /*Object ready*/
            updateMyPage(JSON.parse(el.innerHTML));
            clearInterval(check);
        }else{
            /*Oject not yet ready*/
            check_dl_inc++;
            if(check_dl_inc == dl_cap){
                updateMyPage("");
                clearInterval(check );
                }
        }
    }else{
        /*Missing Dom element*/
        updateMyPage("");
        clearInterval(check );
    }
}, dl_int);
}
```

Comment: Hello Peter, 
What do you mean by updateMyPage function ?

Comment: You won't be able to return a value from a function in a timer. You can however set a global variable (window.my_global = 'new value';) but then you need some way of checking if the variable has been updated once the timer/interval has updated the value. Better yet you can call a function which the example shows. In the function you will have access to the variable you wished to return as it is passed as a parameter to the function. I the function you put your code which will update your page or whatever you needed the returned value to do

Comment: you can easily test the behavior by increasing the dl_int to 2000 and putting console.log(temp_object); in updateMyPage. Then you'll see in the browser console how/when you get an updated value from setInterval

Comment: Thanks Peter. I get it now. I wanted to use the value when it has been render but as no possible, we work around it by realizing everything I want in the SetInterval function itself (included in another function).

Answer (score 2):

I think good idea to use Promises.

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve){

   let check = setInterval(function(){
      el = window.document.getElementById(id);
      if(el){
         if(el.innerHTML.length > 50){
            /*Object ready*/
            temp_object= JSON.parse(el.innerHTML);
            clearInterval(check);
            resolve(temp_object);

            ...

});

promise.then(function(temp_object){
    // Do all yuor needs here
    console.log(temp_object);
});
```

All modern browsers supports Promises 'in box'. Or you can use Bluebird to support older versions. You also can use promise rejecton after few cycles.

Without Promise you just can use callback to function that make all work letter.

Comment: Thanks for this. 
I didn't know those promise function. 
I am looking into it.
But imagine that my element never come, this method will not block the script ?

Comment: I check it and still same problem, the resolve and reject are not updated with the last version of the their value. Closure issue I guess